# Ensure @web alias is explicitly overridden warning on system check

Tags: config

Ensure @web alias is explicitly overridden
^^^I am not sure why this warning shows up in Craft's system report.

I already have defined @web alias in config/general.php per instructions on craft's website. The only things that I can think of which are somewhat non-standard on my install are:

1. In the general.php, I have defined multi-environment configuration for my production and staging environment and as far as I know it is fully compliant with the instructions
2. I also have 2 subdomains `www` and `kb` on a single craft install. My general.php file has @web alias pointing to `www` subdomain. I am not sure if I need to create any explicit alias for the second subdomain (don't know how). Currently, I have defined the second subdomain under Settings>Sites>checkbox "This site has its own base URL"

Can someone enlighten me on what needs to be done here?

Answer (score 2):

> I already have defined @web alias in config/general.php per instructions on craft's website.

Then you are probably done. The warning message is just a warning... it can't detect whether `@web` was set explicitly or determined automatically.